# Read form-list post in flask

Tags: python, api, flask, multipartform-data

I am building an integration from a flask based service to a payments provider, and they just asked me to make an endpoint to receive a POST with multipart/form-data.

I am supposed to receive a list of objects, each with the same parameters, as per the following Curl:

```
  curl -X POST https://vegaz.bet/v1/public/deposit
  -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_HERE" 
  -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" 
  -F "deposits={\"id\":\"1\",\"date\":\"202201011758\",\"character\":\"Mavika\",\"amount\":25}"
```

I am very confused about this form of data, and couldn't find any similar tutorials (before anyone marks this question as a duplicate, check that the answer actually refers to a list of objects via multipart/form-data)

I am currently attempting to write the endpoint as such:

```
@api_blueprint.route("/route", methods=["POST"])
def function_name():

    deposits_data = request.form["deposits"]
```

Will that store a list of dicts to the deposits_dta variable?

Can anyone explain to me how I can handle that POST data?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why are you trying to access data with  `request.files`(not `request.form`)?

Comment: Something I saw in a stackoverflow post, forgot to change it back, editing the question

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: [Handling multipart/form-data natively in Python](https://julien.danjou.info/handling-multipart-form-data-python/). It explains how to do both encoding and decoding using built-in Python modules.